# Alternative Formulation for Direct Sum of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Let's consider the following block diagonal matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3n\times3n}$ with equal diagonal sub matrices $A_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and zero matrices $0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$:

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} A_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & A_1 \end{matrix} \right).$$

According to the definition of the direct sum operator, the following applies:

$$A = A_1\oplus A_1 \oplus A_1 = \oplus_{i=1}^3A_1$$.

Let's consider an equation of the following form:

$$s = B\cdot A\cdot C = B\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} A_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & A_1 \end{matrix} \right)\cdot C = B\cdot(\oplus_{i=1}^3A_1)\cdot C $$ with  $$ s \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1},$$ $$ B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 3n},$$ $$ C \in \mathbb{R}^{3n\times 1}.$$

Is there a way to solve for the diagonal elements in $A_1$ as a function of $s$, $B$, and $C$?. The notation of the direct matrix sum is somehow inconvenient in my opinion. Might there be a different notation such that the system can be solved?
For $n=1$ it is obvious since $A= \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)A_1 $ with scalar $A_1  $. But what about $n>1$?

Comment: I think that if it makes sense to write $A$ as blocks then it is right to write $B=[B_1 B_2 B_3]$ and $C=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^T$ as blocks as well.

Comment: Good point. This would give $s=B_1A_1u_1 + B_2A_1u_2 + B_3A_1u_3 $.

Comment: $B_1A_1u_1+B_2A_1u_2+B_3A_1u_3 = Da$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 1}$ and $a_i = (A_1)_{ii}$ (consider that $A_1$ is a triangular matrix). The question now is how to obtain $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 3}$ as a function of $B$ and $C$. Any idea?